# Stabilizing Radioactive Fission products

Tags: nuclear-engineering

So most fission products have very long half-lives. But i noticed that if a neutron is added the half life becomes a fraction of what it originally was, so could this be a possible method of ridding nuclear waste faster? Would the neutron be absorbed by the nucleus? If not why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, most fission products have quite short half lives. So-called *spent fuel* from civilian is firstly stored for some months. This 'cooling down' period ensures the decay of most short-lived isotopes into more stable ones.

The cooled waste stream is then subjected to reprocessing with the purpose of recovering Plutonium and Uranium.

One residual waste stream contains residual Plutonium, Neptunium, Americium and Curium isotopes. Together these belong to the chemical group of the Actinides. These heavyweight elements arise when Uranium undergoes (multiple) neutron captures without subsequent fission.

Such isotopes, as you mentioned, have very long half lives which causes long term problems of safe storage.  One way of dealing with them would be to use them as fissile materials (absorption of neutron, followed by fission) in so-called *Actinide burners* ([reactors specifically designed to run on this kind of material](http://nucleargreen.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/burning-waste-minor-actinides-and.html)). Development of these reactors has met with very tough technological challenges and as far as I know none are in commercial use at the moment.

Comment: Where is spent fuel from commercial power reactors re-processed?  Here in the U.S.A., I thought that virtually all of the spent fuel from all of our commercial power reactors was still held in "temporary", on-site storage.

Comment: @jameslarge: I believe there is considerable nuclear reprocessing inside the US, although it's possible some of that work is outsourced to other countries. Temporary on-site holding is what I referred to as 'cooling down' period.

Comment: @Gert - no, the US does not reprocess commercial fuel, in a (perhaps futile) attempt to set a trend to reduce the possibility of Plutonium extraction in other countries.

Comment: @JonCuster: I stand corrected.

Comment: @Gert - There was the proposal, and initial construction, of a facility to create mixed oxide (MOX) fuel, blending uranium oxide and plutonium oxide (from nuclear weapons) into something for commercial nuclear power plants to use. This would 'contaminate' the fuel such that the Pu would not be easily extracted for weapons purpose, so reprocessing has been mooted of late...